# Insert an array into a node property in Amazon Neptune using openCypher

Tags: amazon-neptune, opencypher

I am trying to insert an array into a node property in Amazon Neptune using openCypher. Is there a way to do this with openCypher ?

I have tried the following query :

`MERGE (n:Test { name: 'test', colors : ['blue', 'yellow'] })`

Error message :
"detailedMessage": "Expected a simple literal but found List."

If it's not supported how could AWS release it for production if this basic feature is not yet available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neptune only supports Set-based array properties, which are not supported in openCypher specification.

Neptune does support comparable functionality to what you are looking to achieve through the `split()` and `join()` functions as shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/migration-opencypher-rewrites.html#migration-opencypher-rewrites-lists

```
//For writing data
MERGE (n:Test { name: 'test', colors : 'blue, yellow'})

//For reading data
MATCH (n:Test
    WITH n, [tag in split(n.colors, ',') WHERE NOT (color IN ['blue', 'yellow'])] AS colors
    RETURN n
```